# Filtering Java compile error messages in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I started to learn **`Java`** and **`JavaFX`**. Once I started programming using JavaFX, I noticed that when I make only a small mistake in the code, such as omitting a semicolon at the end of a statement, the Java console shows not only that a semicolon is missing, but also an additional enormous amount of messages that are not relevant to the proper functioning of my code, such as

`Access restriction: The type 'Pos' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')`, and many more.

This makes it very difficult to find the actual error, any help would be appreciated.

Can anyone explain me how to filter these less relevant messages in Eclipse?

Comment: You can use the [GREP-CONSOLE-PLUGIN](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grep-console)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the access restrictions settings in eclipse by right clicking on your project -> *Build Path* -> *Configure Build Path*.

Then, in the new window that opens up, click on the *Libraries* tab, expand the entry for the *JRE Sytem Library* you're using (e.g. JavaSE-1.8), select *Access rules* and click the edit button.

You can then add a new access rule from the pop up that this opens. Just enter the *Resolution* as Accessible and the *Rule Pattern* as javafx/** (or whatever path you need to remove warnings for)

Comment: Thanks, this removes about half of the crap, but I still get a lot of lines like "at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)". Do you know how to get rid of those too?

Comment: It depends on what the actual warning is; some you can add _@SuppressWarning_ annotations to (e.g. raw types, deprecated methods) but for others you can go into the _Window_ tab -> _Java_ -> _Compiler_ -> _Errors/Warnings_ and choose which errors you wants to show as warnings and which to ignore. If it's a specific issue you're having though, it would help to expand on the warning message.